# Как сортировать массив по возрастанию времени?

Tags: php, сортировка

Как сортировать такой массив по возрастанию времени?

```
$arr['essay']['1 hours'] = [14.03, 16.14, 18.59,    23.14, 25.43];
$arr['essay']['2 hours'] = [15.09, 17.18, 19.65,    24.20, 26.48];
$arr['essay']['5 hours'] = [15.78, 17.89, 20.34,    24.90, 27.18];
$arr['essay']['8 hours'] = [16.23, 18.19, 20.49,    24.75, 26.88];
$arr['essay']['1 days'] = [17.37, 19.34, 21.63, 25.90, 28.03];
$arr['essay']['3 days'] = [18.36, 20.32, 22.62, 26.88, 29.01];
$arr['essay']['5 days'] = [19.67, 21.63, 23.93, 28.19, 30.32];
$arr['essay']['7 days'] = [21.47, 23.44, 25.73, 29.99, 32.12];
$arr['essay']['1 month'] = [26.88, 28.85, 31.14,    35.40, 37.53];
$arr['essay']['2 month'] = [30.16, 32.12, 34.42,    38.68, 40.81];
$arr['essay']['3 month'] = [33.60, 35.57, 37.86,    42.12, 44.25];
```

ключи ['3 month'] и т.д., это значения, которые должны отображаться на фронтенде в таблице, и напротив этих ключей значения цен, соответствующие этим ключам, т.е. в 1й колонке таблицы будет время, а в последующих колонках будет цена, соответствующая данному времени.
т.е. не важно, какие будут изначально ключи в метках времени при формировании массива, нужно чтобы такие ключи массива были на фронтенде.
Массив динамический, может меняться по возрастанию времени

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php

Comment: @Bloom, кстати, а как формировать правильно такой массив?
интересует как формирование такого массива, так и его вывод на фронтенде. т.е. допустим будет поле input, в котором можно ввести вручную дату, или select с выпадающим списком hours, days, month?